# Classpath order using manifest

Tags: java, jar, log4j, classpath

I am building an application which should be run by `java -jar file.jar`.

The jar contains a manifest file, which [allows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) to set the classpath for runtime.

Now I tried to add `Class-Path: .` in order to allow config files like `log4j.xml` to be placed in the same directory as the jar file.

This seems to work fine if the jar itself does not contain such a file, but java will always prefer the file inside the jar otherwise.

Is there a way to use the manifest file to *prepend* some class in the classpath to force java to first look in that path before looking inside the jar?

(This way I could have a default config inside the jar, but I would be able to override that by placing a custom config file next to the jar.)

Comment: It looks like prepending to the classpath is not possible in a manifest. Some explicit code is therefore needed to do things like finding configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (This way I could have a default config inside the jar, but I would be able to override that by placing a custom config file next to the jar.)

The safest way to do this is probably to make the Log4J configuration step explicit at the top of your `main` method, checking if the config file exists and loading a suitable configuration (with a non-default name, e.g. `com/mypackage/default-log4j.xml`) from inside the JAR if not.  It's not good practice to put a logging configuration file inside a JAR at the "default" location, as it may interfere if your JAR is used on the classpath of another application.

```
URL logConfig = null;
File xmlFile = new File("log4j.xml");
if(xmlFile.exists()) {
  logConfig = xmlFile.toURI().toURL();
} else {
  logConfig = MyMainClassName.class.getResource("default-log4j.xml");
}
DOMConfigurator.configure(logConfig);
```

(exception handling omitted for clarity).

Comment: Maybe this indeed the safest way. Could you please add the corresponding code or a link to the correct documentation?

Comment: @michas something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have it both ways. You will have to change how to invoke the main class.

For example: 
`java -cp .:file.jar <main-class>`

My sample class to test this was:

```
package jarmftest;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("/test.xml"));
    }
}
```

NOTES:

1. You cannot use -cp and -jar at the same time. When using -jar, -cp
   will be ignored
2. Class.getResource() will look for resource relative to the
   package directory, use / to search in classpath

Comment: I am aware of the `-cp` option. But I would really avoid writing a wrapper script. My hope was simply creating a "clickable" jar file. (And specifying the classpath inside the manifest, will do almost the right thing.)